# How to auto redirect url to www

Tags: url, https, cpanel, redirect

I have a website with url **mywebsite.com**
and from `cpanel` I already change the redirection from **mywebsite.com** to **www.mywebsite.com**

and it works, but the problem is
when I type only **mywebsite.com**, the website also running and the URL at browser is **mywebsite.com**.

can someone help me to do auto redirect (**www.mywebsite.com**) my URL when I type URL without www?

Here's my .htacces code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^home\/tssseals\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.mywebsite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't have a condition that catches the URL without WWW  which would be this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$`

which should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$ [NC]` to correctly catch the non-WWW version of the URL.

Simplified:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```